# Magento2 get Selected Customizable options value in addtocart.phtml page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento2.3.3

Magento 2.3.3 How can I get current selected Customizable options value in addtocart.phtml page. I need to pass it along with ajax call parameters to programmatically add product to cart from controller.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to fetch customizable option of products by using below code:

```
$orderObject = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
```

> load by order id

```
$orderId = 1; // YOUR ORDER ID
$order = $orderObject->load($orderId);
```

> load by order increment id

```
$incrementId = '000000001'; // YOUR ORDER INCREMENT ID
$order = $orderObject->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
```

`$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();`
// get all items aren't marked as deleted and that do not have parent item; for e.g. here associated simple products of a configurable products are not fetched

// Order items can also be fetched with the following functions
`$items = $order->getAllItems();` // get all items that are not marked as deleted
`$items = $order->getItems();` // get all items

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();        
    if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {        
        foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
            echo 'Title: ' . $option['label'] . '<br />';
            echo 'ID: ' . $option['option_id'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Type: ' . $option['option_type'] . '<br />';
            echo 'Value: ' . $option['option_value'] . '<br />' . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get create programmatically add product to cart. How will I have increment id?